# MySql select query joins not giving expected answer

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a simple attendance system for technicians. Days attended is stored in a table called tech_logins. It has 1 record per technician per date. The jobs the technicians perform are stored in a table called logs. This table holds all the jobs that the technicians complete. It also has two fields that relate to the tech_logins table. They are called technician_id and dos.

The logs table can contain jobs that are linked to the technician but with a dos not linked i.e. when someone enters a job for the technician but on a date (dos) when the technician was not there.

I am trying to get all the jobs, for each technician only for the dos dates that link with the login_date in the tech_logins table. This sql only return records for a single technician and a single date:

```
SELECT tech_logins.tech_id, 
       tech_logins.login_date 
FROM   tech_logins 
INNER JOIN `logs`
       ON tech_logins.login_date = `logs`.dos 
       AND tech_logins.tech_id = `logs`.technician_id
```

Any help or guidelines will be greatly appreciated.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tech_logins` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tech_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tech_id` (`tech_id`,`login_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `completed` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `patient_first_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `patient_last_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dos` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `study_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ICD9` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_doctor_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `insurance_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `insurance_no` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorization_no` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referral_no` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reading_doctor_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `technician_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `biller` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=79 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Your description is a little hard to follow. Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statements for the relevant tables.

Comment: A sample of the data and what you would expect back as a result set would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your query structure  appears correct.  It is likely you have data issues where the data in the two tables do not actually match properly on your two join columns.

Why don't you try selecting a small set of the two columns separately, first from tech_logins.  then query the logs table using the two columns of a couple of the rows returned from tech_logins.   One step at a time and you'll find your answer.  You are doing the sql correctly.

Comment: agreed there are data issues; also the table structure is a bit off. FK between these tables should be on `ID` alone.

Comment: The linked fields seem just fine. The ID should be the FK but a need to use the login_date and the tech_id.

Comment: Well, this is the problem: The tech_logins table contains only 1 record per technician per day. The logs table may have multiple logs per technician per day. Also, the logs table may contain records for the technician that were entered by back-office staff on a day when the technician was not there. Hence there is not an entry in the tech_logins for the dos in the logs table.

Comment: Think understand you now.  Here's a plan. You want to do right join to the logs table so that days the tech did not login you still get their logs. After that you do a distinct by (date, login) to get a single record per technician per day that they (or their back office proxy) put entries in the logs .

Comment: This is an example of a single query for 1 techician and the correct results: SELECT
`logs`.technician_id,
`logs`.dos
FROM
`logs`
WHERE
`logs`.technician_id = 16 AND
`logs`.dos = '2013/02/28' Results:16 2013-02-28
16 2013-02-28
16 2013-02-28
16 2013-02-28

Comment: Well, I doo not want the jobs listed when the technician was not logged in. I only want the jobs per technician, per day. The jobs entered by the back office are irrelevant.

Comment: If you want "per technician per day", you may want to use `GROUP BY tech_logins.id, tech_logins.login_date`

Comment: To add to this, there may be days when a technician logs in but does not enter any logs. i.e. there will be an entry in the tech_logins table but no jobs done for that technician for that particular day.

Answer (score -1):

Change date join with following

```
 DATE_FORMAT( tech_logins.login_date, '%d %m     %Y')
 = DATE_FORMAT( 'logs'.dos, '%d %m %Y')
```

Update
If this doesn't work than replace inner join with left join just to check if there is any date issue.

Comment: Formatting the date gives a syntax error: SELECT tech_logins.tech_id, 
       tech_logins.login_date
FROM
tech_logins
INNER JOIN `logs` ON tech_logins.tech_id = `logs`.technician_id AND DATE_FORMAT( tech_logins.login_date, '%d %m   %Y')= DATE_FORMAT( 'logs'.dos, '%d %m %Y')

Comment: Replace 'logs' with logs.

Comment: Same syntax error with left join.

Comment: Use your initial query and replace inner join with left and check whether dates in both tables are same.

Comment: Yes, dates are the same.